# Why redis cluster resharding is not automatically?

Tags: redis

When I add a node in a redis cluster, it has 0 hash slots. Why redis cluster doesn't automatically does a resharding operation in order to make the new node fully functional?

Comment: http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

Comment: I already read that. It says that I have to run that command in order to reshard the cluster. My question is: why this is not accomplished automatically by the cluster? For example if I have a huge data amount and I need to add a new node on the fly, I want to use that new node immediately.

Comment: Well, obviously, because it's not implemented. @antirez is super-smart, so there must be good reasons for this, I'm sure.

Comment: The [feature request](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/4052) which asks for the same thing is still in the open state and it's part of [Redis 6 plans](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/4053) (moved from Redis 4 plan)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://redis.io/topics/partitioning), redis supports now automatic partitioning.

Comment: What I see as of now in the document you provided, is "however currently there is no way for redis-cli to automatically rebalance the cluster checking the distribution of keys across the cluster nodes and intelligently moving slots as needed.".

How do you say it supports it?

Answer (score 1):

The process of adding a node consists of two steps:

1. Introduce the node to other nodes via `CLUSTER MEET` so that all the nodes start to communicate via cluster bus
2. Make the node to act as Master via `CLUSTER ADDSLOTS` or as a slave via `CLUSTER REPLICATE`

The separation helps to keep the commands simple.

Automatic resharding is part of the [Redis 4.2 roadmap](https://gist.github.com/antirez/a3787d538eec3db381a41654e214b31d)

Answer (score -1):

regard of my expirence, automatic reshard is not i want.

the case i was dealing with is that some node has high read throughput(100k qps), so i add new nodes to reshard only these high load node for the purpose of decreasing the pressure.

you may ask why the load is different? Cause we use hash tag (eg. {user}123456 )to ensure the same kind data stored on the same node.

so automatic reshard is useless.

Comment: Automatic sharding is not a useless function. Just doesn't solve problem in your case. Even if Redis offers this feature(automatic resharding), I think the manual resharding feature will always be available.